# In KDE Konsole, vim mapping F1-F5 does not work

Tags: vim, kde-plasma, konsole

Map `F1-F5` will fail, while map `F6-F12` is ok.

The same map can work in *Guake*. So it must be the problem with *Konsole*.

How to deal with?

```
Kubuntu:13.04
Konsole:2.11.3
Vim: 7.4.5
KDE: 4.11.3
```

Comment: Try going into your keyboard settings and selecting Xterm.  Some newer Konsoles map the function keys to escape sequences instead of there usual functions

Comment: The keyboard setting in Konsole? If it is that, the default is XFree4, the other two is Linux console and Solaries console, no Xterm?

Comment: That's the one.  Mine has an Xterm option, but try linux console.  It should work

Comment: In General, the TERM=Xterm, only when I change it to the Solaris console, it works, not Linux. Thanks!

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later?? If it is resolved, please select an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to `Settings -> Edit Current Profile -> Keyboard`, you can select the bindings as follows:

[image]